# trying to implement js textualizer

Tags: javascript

I am trying to use js textualizer from http://kiro.me/projects/textualizer.html but It is not working for me, I have a js fiddle going I am wondering if anyone could figure this out.

http://jsfiddle.net/Zk2tr/2/

code

html

```
<script src="https://raw.github.com/krisk/textualizer/master/textualizer.min.js"></script>
<div id="output"></div>
Not Working
```

js

```
var list = ['first blurb', 'second blurb', 'third blurb'];  // list of blurbs

var txt = $('#output');  // The container in which to render the list

var options = {
  duration: 1000,          // Time (ms) each blurb will remain on screen
  rearrangeDuration: 1000, // Time (ms) a character takes to reach its position
  effect: 'random',        // Animation effect the characters use to appear
  centered: true           // Centers the text relative to its container
}

txt.textualizer(list, options); // textualize it!
txt.textualizer('start'); // start
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this example:

> http://jsfiddle.net/Zk2tr/9/

In order for it to work correctly, you need to add some initial styles. Example:

```
#output {
  font-size: 40px;
  height: 200px;
  margin-top: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  text-align: center;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}
```